# Determine if one_value_keyword provided to cmake_parse_arguments() was given without value

Tags: cmake

Documentation is here [cmake_parse_arguments()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html#cmake-parse-arguments)

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)

function(func)
   set(options OPTION)
   set(oneValueArgs VALUE)
   set(multiValueArgs MULTIVALUE)
   cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 "" "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}")

   if(NOT DEFINED _VALUE)
      set(_VALUE undefined)
   endif()
   message("_VALUE:${_VALUE}")
endfunction(func)

func()             ## undefined
func(VALUE)        ## undefined!!!
func(VALUE xxx)    ## xxx
```

`cmake -P test.cmake`

```
_VALUE:undefined
_VALUE:undefined
_VALUE:xxx
```

In function body how to determine if it was called with empty VALUE or without VALUE?
How to disambiguate first and second calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of missed value, CMake (>= 3.15) adds the corresponding named keyword in the list variable `<prefix>_KEYWORDS_MISSING_VALUES`.

Here is the solution for your question:

```
cmake_policy(VERSION 3.17)

function(foo)
    set(_options)
    set(_one_value_args VALUE)
    set(_multi_value_args)
    cmake_parse_arguments(
        PARSE_ARGV 0 _arg 
        "${_options}" 
        "${_one_value_args}" 
        "${_multi_value_args}"
      )

    if("VALUE" IN_LIST _arg_KEYWORDS_MISSING_VALUES)
        message(STATUS "VALUE: missed value")
    elseif(NOT DEFINED _arg_VALUE)
        message(STATUS "VALUE: undefined")
    else()
        message(STATUS "VALUE: got the value `${_arg_VALUE}`")
    endif()
endfunction()

foo()             ## undefined
foo(VALUE)        ## missed!!!
foo(VALUE bar)
```

Output:

```
$ cmake -P test.cmake
-- VALUE: undefined
-- VALUE: missed value
-- VALUE: got the value `bar`
```

Comment: What is difference between function overloads `PARSE_ARGV 0` and `${ARGN}`?

Comment: It's mostly about `macro` vs `function` cases. Please, read the docs mentioned.

Comment: @kyb, Also, I encourage you to use some **non-empty** prefix to avoid (possibly important) variables *shadowing* and giving an extra (semantic) hint to the reader about *what kind of the variable is this*.

Comment: Thank you for advise.

Comment: running the same code on RPi cmake 3.13.4 I always got empty _arg_KEYWORDS_MISSING_VALUES and VALUE: undefined in second line

Comment: Reading the documentation I found that `_KEYWORDS_MISSING_VALUES` appeared in version 3.15. :(

Comment: @kyb, that is why I gave you a *hint* in the code by setting the `cmake_policy` to 3.17 (the latest release). There is no reason to use an old release if we have a newer one :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212988/discussion-between-zaufi-and-kyb).